# Declaring variable in jQuery syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got my jQuery working fine in jsfiddle. However, it won't work in my actual application because of the dom.

I'm new at this, i think I might be using the wrong syntax or something?

[Here's my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fLqSn/), note that it works if you select domready but not wrap.. I'm really confused

Here's the actual code:

```
$curr = $('#first');

$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.next').click(function () {
    $curr.hide();
    $curr = $curr.next();
    $curr.show();
});
});

$(document).ready(function () {
$('.previous').click(function () {
    $curr.hide();
    $curr = $curr.prev();
    $curr.show();
  });
});
```

Comment: Your code has to either be in a "load" or "ready" handler, or "no wrap" at the **end** of the `<body>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $curr = $('#first');

   $('.next').click(function () {
      $curr.hide();
      $curr = $curr.next();
      $curr.show();
   });

   $('.previous').click(function () {
      $curr.hide();
      $curr = $curr.prev();
     $curr.show();

   });
});
```

No need for multiple document.ready events in your case :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip :) makes sense.

Works perfectly in jsfiddle, in my application I get an "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined " though.. any ideas?

Comment: Yes, that means that the jquery library has not been included in your page. http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_install.asp....Either download it from the CDN, else download it store it locally on your PC an give the relative path..hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code instead:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $curr = $('#first');

    $('.next').click(function () {
        $curr.hide();
        $curr = $curr.next();
        $curr.show();
    });

    $('.previous').click(function () {
        $curr.hide();
        $curr = $curr.prev();
        $curr.show();   
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this works in jsfiddle. When I put it on my actual application I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined " "anonymous function" error though.. pointing to this JS.

Any ideas? There are no typo